# Example where $P(n)$ is not valid for induction?

Tags: linear-algebra, induction

I am studing for my math exam on friday and at the moment I am doing a examples about induction:

However, I am struggeling at this question:

Give an example where $P(n)$ is not valid even if the induction base is correct?
Give an example where $P(n)$ is not valid even if the induction conclusion is correct?

For the first question I would say:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n k = {n\cdot (n+1)\over 2}$$
because of $P(0)=0$

Any ideas for the second question?

Comment: You meant $\sum_{i=0}^ni$ maybe? In any case $P(n)$ is a proposition,I think, so $P(0)=0$ makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for

- a proposition $P(n)$ (where $n$ is a natural number) such that $P(0)$ is true but not all $P(n)$ are true,
- a proposition $P(n)$ (where $n$ is a natural number) such that $P(n)\Rightarrow P(n+1)$ is true for all $n$, but not all $P(n)$ are true.

The first is easy: take for $P(n)$ the proposition $n=0$.

For the second, you can take a proposition $P(n)$ that is false for all $n$. Indeed, the implications $P(n)\Rightarrow P(n+1)$ will then be correct for all $n$ because an implication is true if its antecedent is false. As a concrete example, you can take for $P(n)$ the proposition $0=1$.